# Animation :enter :leave not firing for @ngIf inside ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-animations

So I have this component. Let's call it `AnimationComponent`:

```
<div
  id="{{id}}"
  [@defaultAnimationSet]='animationState'
  (@defaultAnimationSet.start)="onAnimationStart($event)"
  (@defaultAnimationSet.done)="onAnimationEnd($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

where the animation state is set automatically, based on the type provided as prop. `animationState` flips between 'default' and the `type` you provide as prop. Say you provided `opacity`, it'll flip between 'default' and 'opacity'.

Now I use this `AnimationComponent` here:

```
<app-animation [type]='activeTransitionType'>
  <div class='content' *ngIf='showContent'>
    Some content here!
  </div>
</app-animation>
```

Here's one of the animations I have in `defaultAnimationSet`:

```
const opacityEnterAnimation = animation([
  query(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('1s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
  ], { optional: true })
]);

const opacityLeaveAnimation = animation([
  query(':leave', [
    animate('0.25s',
      style({ opacity: 0 })
    ),
  ], { optional: true })
]);

const opacityAnimation = [
  state('opacity', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  transition('void => opacity', [
    useAnimation(opacityEnterAnimation)
  ]),
  transition('opacity => void', [
    useAnimation(opacityLeaveAnimation)
  ])
];

export const defaultAnimationSet = [
 ...opacityAnimation
];
```

**Expected**: Apply the opacity enter and leave animation on the *ngIf content transcluded within this component.
**Actual**: Doesn't work at all! The `:enter` and `:leave` seems to find the entered / left content, but doesn't apply the transitions on them.

Comment: Just curious if you ever found a solution for this? I'm trying to accomplish the exact same thing.